# Remove a older Version of man-db on a Raspberry with Debian Squeeze, man-db breaks less (<<456)

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

for some people this would be easy but I've been googling a lot and I can't find a solution.

My problem is tha I want to install man-db_2.6.3-3_armhf.deb on a raspberry, but when I try to install it I get the error that:

```
man-db breaks less (<<456)
 less (version 444-4) is present and installed
```

how I install my package is like this:

```
dpkg -i man-db_2.6.3-3_armhf.deb
```

I tried to unistall the current version of man-db with

```
dpkg -r man-db
dpkg --purge man-db
```

But I just cant get rid of the latter version, any help will be very appreciated.

Just to make you note, I can't use apt-get to install packages from internet because I am through a proxy with NTLM authentication, I tried a lot to configure my proxy with other packages, path and more but is not working, so thats why I am installing packages with dpkg.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg --ignore-depends -i man-db_2.6.3-3_armhf.deb
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I tried that one but I get this:

`dpkg: error: --ignore-depends needs a valid package name but '-i' is not: illegal package name in specifier '-i': must start with alphanumeric character`

Comment: Sorry bout that; give this a whirl:    dpkg -i --ignore-depends=less man-db_2.6.3-3_armhf.deb

Comment: Thank you, now it worked, but it seems that the instalation is corrupt or something because I am not able to use the command man, but the package was installed ingnoring the former version, thanks !!

Comment: This is what we sometimes call 'dependency hell.'  Try downloading/installing a version of less newer than 456.

Comment: I found a lower version but not for the Raspberry architecture, now I am fighting to get back the `man`

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for (to me.)  http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/man-db

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the architecture of the version of Raspberry is not listed, only 'armel' and I need 'armhf'. The origin of my problem is that I was trying to install a version of java (1.3.0_02) but with not success, a long story, but I found that version is not working with arm cpus. So I tried to installed Alien to make RPM packages to DEB and there is where I started to fight with dependecies. I installed Java but with version 7, now I have to  figure out how to installed the older version on the Raspberry PI, but thats another story, thanks for your help.